# Linux Desktop Keeps freezing

Tags: ubuntu

I have a Ubuntu 10.04 , I have recently been playing Minecraft by using the,"Minecraft.jar" After about 6-10 Minutes, My desktop suddenly freezes. Sometimes, I just spam **Ctrl**+**ALT**+***  Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Then I would have to restart my computer, but would happen *AGAIN* later. Is there anyway to stop this from happening?

Comment: If your hardware supports it you should upgrade your machine to a newer release. Ubuntu 10.04 is end-of-life. This might, but not necessarily will, solve the problems you are having.

Comment: @Anthon Yes, i've been seeing a pop-up saying,"SYSTEM-UPDATE-AVAILABLE!" But i've been ignoring it while I was gaming. So thanks for your help!

Comment: Be conservative with what you do with old machines. My Dell D800 (from 2003 or so) will not run with newer nvidia drivers than those that come with 10.04. I always keep the old version on a partition and use a second to try newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

There was something (kind of) similar to your case. That case was (kind of or at least became a bit better) solved after uninstalling the game and Java package then reinstalling both.

You may also consider checking for any update that might have been recently released by your VGA vendor.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will try this immediately, I will notify you if this doesn't work.

Comment: My Linux is now updated to,"UBUNTU 14.04 LTS" Is this an end of life?

Comment: @Ben: I thought your hardware might not support Linux' newer version. Now that you've successfully upgraded, did it solve your problem? 14.04 looks like to be a nice thing, after all.